# Predict multiband raster with PLS model object in R

Tags: r

I have a Partial Least Squares Regression model object in R that I would like to use to predict values as spatial patterns on a map.

So far however, this is not working for me. The PLS model was processed in R (PLS package) and the input is a table:

```
Dependent variable   Indepentent var. 1   Indepentend var ...     Indepented var. 101
Value                value                value                   value
Value                value                value                   value
...                  ...                  ...                     ...
```

So i want to predict the value of the dependant variable according to the 101 indepentent variables for each pixel on the map. However the PLS model input is a table and the prediction data consists of a BSQ file with 101 bands (layers). So the data structure of the training data and the prediction data is completely different.

Someone told me that I should stack the BSQ map and that I could just use the Predict fuction after that. This is not working.

How can I somehow coerce the 101 bands in the BSQ file to a structure on which I will be able to make prediction for each pixel based on my PLS model? Bair in mind that I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to R.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(pls)


#   the dir and name of the plsr model object
modDir        <- "H:/Process"
modName       <- "Model"

#   the dir and type of the remote sensing image
rsDir         <- "H:/data"
rsName        <- "Hyper.bsq"

# Read the PLSR model
setwd("H:/Process")
# setwd(paste(modDir, modName, sep= "/"))
m             <- load(list.files()[grep("Model", list.files())]) 
mod           <- get(m)

# Read the RS image
setwd(rsDir)
rs            <- stack(rsName)


predict(mod, rs)
```

Thanks! Arend

Answer (score 0):

The structure of `rs` needs to be exactly the same as the structure of the data that was used to fit the model. In general, fitting the model will be done using (this uses the example data):

```
library(plsr)
yarn.pls <- plsr(density ~ NIR, 6, data = yarn)
```

where `yarn[['NIR']]` is actually a matrix that has the same amount of rows as the overall `data.frame` it is part of:

```
> str(yarn)
'data.frame':   28 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ NIR    : num [1:28, 1:268] 3.07 3.07 3.08 3.08 3.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ density: num  100 80.2 79.5 60.8 60 ...
 $ train  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

In order to make predictions, you need to feed predict a `data.frame` that also has a `NIR` variable (with that name) which effectively is a matrix with the same amount of columns (i.e. bands in your case), and a number of rows. For each row, a prediction of `density` is made.

So, take a good look at your training data (use `str`) and mimic that for the prediction.